# Функция для подсчёта слайдов slick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать данную функцию подсчёта слайдов универсальной(если на странице будут несколько слайдеров), чтобы просто пользоваться меняя параметры: 1) селектор по слайдеру 2) селектор по div со счётчиком.

Вот что есть на данный момент:

https://jsfiddle.net/st_iv/Lurowze5/

```
//custom function showing current slide
      var $status = $('.pagingInfo');
      var $slickElement = $('.slider');

      $slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
          //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
          var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
          $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
      });
```

То что пытаюсь сделать:

```
function countSlides(status, slider) {
    slider.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        status.text(i + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
    });
}
```

Comment: Я проверил функцию, что вы написали. А что не работает то? Да и что вы имеете ввиду под _универсальностью_?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Пытаюсь туда передать селекторы но не выходит.
function countSlides($('.status'), $('.slider'))

Comment: `function countSlides($('.status'), $('.slider'))` - странная запись. Если это объявление функции, то оно синтаксически не правильно. В списке аргументов должны быть перечислены имена аргументов: `function countSlides(status, slider) { /* Какой-то код */ }`. Если же это вызов функции, то там не должно быть ключевого слова `function`, т.е.: `countSlides($('.status'), $('.slider'));`.